# pam_unix.so Prints "authentication failure" on Successful Login

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pam, sshd, pam-unix

`/var/log/messages` shows a message like

```
Jul  6 13:00:05 orbit-32 sshd[11517]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.98.106  user=admin
```

although my password authentication suceeds and I am logged in. I am using PAM with `pam_unix.so` as the only plugin. How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable `audit` logging in pam_unix and allow debug logging using syslog.conf you will see the following:

```
 debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
 ...
 pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.98.106  user=admin
```

Login method 'none' turns out to be sshd trying to login with an empty password. This is apparently a part of the PAM specification, see http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/users/43558 for details.

To fix it, set `PermitEmptyPasswords` to 'no' in in sshd_config. This will prevent sshd from trying an empty password against PAM.